# convert Spring ResponseEntity to ASP.NET CORE equivalent

Tags: java, asp.net, spring-boot, rest, asp.net-core

I am new to C# and looking for an equivalent of Springboot's ResponseEntity in C#.

How can I convert this spring boot Java code to C#?

Note: I have removed the inner logic of the function for obvious reasons.

```
@Autowired
Environment env;    // what is the equivalent of this in C#

[HttpPut,Route("/create")]
public ResponseEntity<Integer> text(@RequestBody String json)
{
    ...
    if (true)
    {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(100, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    // error has occurend, hence we send code 102
    return new ResponseEntity<>(102, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Comment: So essentially, you just want to create a webapi ?

Comment: Yes, web API in c#. I have all that set and ready. I am just looking for a way to convert some legacy code.

Comment: There are a lot of ways to write a WebAPI endpoint. From what I see, you are using ASP.NET Core, not ASP.NET. But you say ASP.NET in your tags. First thing's first: Learn what Dependency Injection is. It's extremely important. It will answer most of your questions. And remember: C# is a language, not a framework. You want to learn to write a WebAPI in the C# language using ASP.NET Core as your framework. That's an important specifier.

Comment: I do not now what is `Environment` in springboot, but you can try `IWebHostEnvironment` or `Configuration`.

Comment: @Karney. It is basically an object that allows to retreive either properties from Windows or Docker envrionment Variable or application.properties.

Comment: @Karney. I have found something: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment?view=net-5.0